# Programmatically create button in webview and set click event

Tags: android, html, webview

I want to show a number of lines of text as well as buttons in my webview programmatically in android.

Let's say I have to set 5 lines of text and 5 buttons in my webview where each button button do call a single method with different parameters.
e.g. If I press button1 I want to call `myMethod(var1)` and if I press button2 I want to call `myMethod(var2)`

Everything should be in single webview (exactly like the attached image). I can show any lines of text in webview but problem is not able to load buttons and call method for every button.

for loading only text I am using following code:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
     text.append("-").append("Anything").append("<br><br>");
}

webViewChild.loadData("<body style=\"font-size:15px\">" + text.toString() + "</body>", "text/html", "utf-8");
```

I don't I am clear enough in my question, so if you want further clarification please ask.

Thanks.

[image]